# C# WebApi как развернуть

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Подскажите как разворачивается WebAPI, что такое

> "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",

какие данные нужно вписывать вместо локол хоста и от чего, нужен ли домен, какие порты должны быть открыты ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/ Половина ваших вопросов не имеют никакого ответа, пока вы не решите, КУДА ИМЕННО вы будете разворачивать ваше webapi.

Comment: [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - вот ещё полезная ссылка

Comment: https://www.cyberforum.ru/asp-net-core/thread2463412.html вот тут обсуждалось

Comment: домен не нужен если вы планируете указывать IP, однако нынче это моветон. Порты должны быть открыты те, которые указаны в конфигах. В вашем конфиге это 5000 и 5001, но обычно разворачивают на стандартных 80 и 443, реже - на 8000 или 8080. Тут уж всё зависит от того, что именно вы ходите и зачем. Остальные вопросы - вам нужно решить что и как вы хотите разворачивать, тогда будет и понимание, как это делать.